# Multiprocessing with a function that returns a value, then appending that value

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've seen bundles of questions on here about multiprocessing, none of which seem to answer my specific problem.

Obviously my problem/function is much more complex, but I've tried to simplify it as much as possible. My function currently takes around 5 mins to run an instance of so would be great if I could get this working in parallel.

Below is basically how I am running things currently, looping thru each 'name' in my list, passing it thru the function and then appending it to the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Matthew': [4, 9, 6], 'Mark': [2, 3, 5], 'Luke': [10, 1, 8], 'John': [20, 22, 21]})

def sum_funct(name,df):
    df = df
    return int(df[name].sum())

totals_dict = {}

names = ['Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John']

for name in names:
    totals_dict[name] = sum_funct(name,df)

print(totals_dict)

{'Matthew': 19, 'Mark': 10, 'Luke': 19, 'John': 63}
```

What I'd love to be able to do is use multiprocessing in the `for name in names:` bit, but so far I can't find anything about being able to use the values a function returns while multiprocessing. I've come across some answers which touch on functions that return values but none have been of any help.

Comment: look into `multiprocessing.Pool`

Answer (score 2):

The ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures could be used for this. For example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from pandas import DataFrame
from functools import partial

def sum_funct(df, name):
    return name, df[name].sum()

def main():
    dict_ = {'Matthew': [4, 9, 6], 'Mark': [2, 3, 5], 'Luke': [10, 1, 8], 'John': [20, 22, 21]}
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        total_dict = dict(executor.map(partial(sum_funct, DataFrame(dict_)), dict_))
        print(total_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{'Matthew': 19, 'Mark': 10, 'Luke': 19, 'John': 63}
```

**Note:**

If the dictionary has more keys than you have CPUs you should probably consider calculating a suitable value for *max_workers* (passed to ProcessPoolExecutor)

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your input. I get this error message '_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function sum_funct at 0x136674d30>: attribute lookup sum_funct on __main__ failed' when running your code. I've had this error message when trying every multiprocessing solution so far. Any ideas?

Comment: @topbantz What Python version? Also, are you sure you copied my code in its entirety (including the \_\_name\_\_ check)?

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks again for the help. My version is 3.1. And yes, copied the whole thing in it's entirety but this error message has popped up before when looking at other multiprocessing solutions, so don't think it's specific to your code. My Macbook Air is about 2 years old now, and is one of the M1 processor ones. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @topbantz The code in my answer runs without issue on Python 3.10.5 (macOS 12.5). I can't understand how or why you'd end up with Python 3.1 (which was released over 12 years ago) on a 2 year old Mac

Comment: Ah sorry I mean 3.10 was just rounding to 1DP!

Comment: Anyway no worries, thanks anyway for your help, think I'll have to shelve multiprocessing